# How can I find the max of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `flowdata` of this shape `(50, 100, 14)`.

The data basically corresponds to `50 bins, 100 events in each bin, and 14 days of data per event`

Now, I want to create the max of every day (for every bin and corresponding event).

For now, I am doing this:

```
flowbinmax = []
for b in range(nbins):  #nbins=50
    floweventsmax = []   #Cleared for each bin

    for e in range(nevents):  #nevents=100
        floweventsmax.append(max(flowdata[b][e]))

    flowbinmax.append(floweventsmax)
```

Is there a better/simpler way of doing this? I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: `np.max(flowdata, axis=2)`?

Comment: Darn it. Thanks a lot! @Psidom

Comment: Quick question: `np.max(dryflow, axis=(1,2))` - Does this give me bin-wise max of each 100 event max? Looks like it, but just want to be sure..

Comment: `np.max(dryflow, axis=(1,2))` gives the max value for each bin -

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will spend some time with documentation. This is super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The numpy array [amax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax) function has the ability to select an axis.  This allows you to select the maximum over one or more axes (dimensions).

The code you provided looks to be providing the maximum for a given bin over all events/days.  To get the maximum over a given day, try:

```
daymax = np.amax(flowdata, axis=2)
```

Comment: What is the difference between amax and max?

Comment: As far as I can tell, np.max and np.amax are identical.  It looks like np.max is just an alias for np.amax.